# The correct way to say easier

Tags: vocabulary

Is "more easy" a correct grammatical way of saying "easier"? What other ways can you express the word "easier"?

Comment: What's wrong with *easier*?  In general, I would recommend not using *more easy*.

Comment: @Jim My mother and I were having an argument. I just wanted to know if it was grammatically correct.

Comment: You might find this [discussion on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67991/much-more-easy-versus-much-easier) useful. The consensus seems to be that "more easy" is grammatically correct, but only used in edge cases. You tend to be better off with "easier".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern English, it's *easier*. The form *more easy* used to be fairly common but it has just about disappeared. British English and American English evolved very similarly on this issue.

[image: easier,more easy]

Usually, when adding *-er* results in at most two syllables, the single-word comparative is preferred, while *more* is preferred otherwise: *harder*, *faster*, *simpler*, *odder*, *more even*, *more difficult*. There are however many exceptions.